# Cannot use add() method for object list

Tags: java, tree

I have a Node class and I want each Node to have a list of its leaves. For this, I create an instance variable ArrayList(). When I try to add a Node to this list I get a NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.ArrayList.add(Object)" because "this.nextSibling" is null. Why is this happening?

This is my code:

```
public class Node {

   private String name;
   private Node firstChild;
   private ArrayList<Node> nextSibling;

   Node (String n, Node d, ArrayList<Node> r) {
      this.name = n;
      this.firstChild = d;
      this.nextSibling = r;
   }

   Node() {
      this("", null, null);
   }

   Node (String s) {
      this(s, null, null);
   }

   Node (String s, Node p) {
      this(s, p, null);
   }

   Node(String s, ArrayList<Node> lst) {
      this(s, null, lst);
   }

   public void setFirstChild (Node d) {
      firstChild = d;
   }

   public void addNextSibling (Node r) {
         nextSibling.add(r);
   }

   public static Node parsePostfix (String s) {
      if (checkForNoData(s)) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Invalid input: " + s);
      }
      Stack<Node> nodeStack = new Stack<>();

      List<String> nodeNamesCheck = new ArrayList<>();
      List<String> nodeNames = getNodeNames(s);
      int y = nodeNames.size() - 1;

      Node root = new Node(nodeNames.get(y));

      nodeStack.push(root);
      nodeNamesCheck.add(nodeNames.get(y));

      for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         if (s.charAt(i) == ')') {
            y--;
            Node firstChild = new Node(nodeNames.get(y), new ArrayList<>());
            nodeNamesCheck.add(nodeNames.get(y));
            nodeStack.peek().setFirstChild(firstChild);
            nodeStack.push(firstChild);
         } if (s.charAt(i) == ',') {
            if (!nodeStack.empty())
               nodeStack.pop();
            y--;
            Node nextSibling = new Node(nodeNames.get(y), new ArrayList<>());
            nodeNamesCheck.add(nodeNames.get(y));
            nodeStack.peek().addNextSibling(nextSibling);
            nodeStack.push(nextSibling);
         } else if (s.charAt(i) == '(') {
            if (!nodeStack.empty()) {
               nodeStack.pop();
            }
         }
      }
      if (nodeNames.size() != nodeNamesCheck.size() && nodeNames.size() != 1)
         throw new RuntimeException("Invalid input: " + s);
      return root;
   }
}
```

The parsePostfix(String s) method takes a tree as a string and re-creates this with Nodes. An example input would be "(H,G,F)E,(D,C,)B)A".

Comment: This is confusing. You say you want each node to store an array of its leaves, but then your node instances have a reference called `nextSibling`. To me the concept of next sibling has really nothing to do with the concept "all my leaves". What would it mean for the first entry in that array list to be a node that also has an array list? Are you really going to duplicate all sibling references in all their array lists? And how does this relate with *leaves*? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   private ArrayList<Node> nextSibling;

   Node (String n, Node d, ArrayList<Node> r) {
      this.name = n;
      this.firstChild = d;
      this.nextSibling = r;
   }

   Node() {
      this("", null, null);
   }

   Node (String s) {
      this(s, null, null);
   }

   Node (String s, Node p) {
      this(s, p, null);
   }
```

You are, very explicitly, setting `nextSibling` to `null` in the last three constructors.  So of course `this.nextSibling` is null.

If you don't want that to happen, you will need to set it to something other than null, like `new ArrayList<>()`.

(As @trincot mentions, your variable names also seem confusing, as `nextSibling` is a strange name for a list of leaves -- which would be children, not siblings.)